# random string appeared at end of URL - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, random

I recently installed the Master Slider plugin.

I noticed shortly after that there was a random string appearing at the end of my URLs:

`www.mysite.com/?v=79cba1185463` and
`www.mysite.com/products/?v=79cba1185463` ...

I decided to remove the plugin, clear the cache etc...

The random string is still showing a the end of my URLs

Does anyone know if Master Slider was in fact to blame. and how to remove this string?

Comment: what caching plugin do you use?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference for anyone else who comes up against this...

I have found out that using Woocommerce's Geolocate Caching option adds a random string to the end of the URLs.

After changing it to geolocate only the random string no longer appears.
[image: Woocommerce Settings]